# How to print all columns but last 2?

Tags: shell, awk

How to print all columns but last 2?

e.g

```
input :echo FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02_20130820_181008
output : FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02
delimiter : _ (underscore)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an RE that describes the last 2 fields:

```
awk '{sub(/_[^_]*_[^_]*$/,"")}1'
```

or:

```
sed 's/_[^_]*_[^_]*$//'
```

e.g.:

```
$ echo FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02_20130820_181008 | awk '{sub(/_[^_]*_[^_]*$/,"")}1'
FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02

$ echo FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02_20130820_181008 | sed 's/_[^_]*_[^_]*$//'
FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02
```

Te above will work with any modern awk and any sed on any system.

Answer (score 8):

for your example, this awk one liner should do:

```
awk -F'_' -v OFS='_' 'NF-=2' file
```

test:

```
kent$  awk -F'_' -v OFS='_' 'NF-=2' <<< "FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02_20130820_181008"
FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02
```

Comment: On OSX you need to add `$1=$1` to force awk to recalculate the line. `NF-=2{$1=$1;print}` (@anubhava)

Answer (score 1):

use this awk command:

```
 awk -F "_" '{for (i=1; i<=NF-2; i++) {printf ("%s", $i); if (i<NF-2) printf "_"} print ""}'
 FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02
```

Comment: root:aukbckas:/opt/networker/NW_tools/log # echo FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02_20130820_181008 | awk -F "_" '{for (i=1 i<=NF-2; i++) print $i}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: You need to use quotes in echo: `echo 'FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02_20130820_181008'`

Comment: You need to define `OFS` to have `_` as output field separator. `BEGIN{OFS=FS}` does it.

Comment: @fedorqui: I am already including `_` here: `if (i<NF-2) printf "_"`

Comment: Yes I saw it. However, I think it is way more clear to define it outside the printing part. This way it is easier to update in case the field separator changes.

Comment: Any time you get the error message `awk: syntax error near line 1 awk: bailing out near line 1` it means you are using old, broken awk which is /usr/bin/awk on Solaris. Use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk or gawk instead.

Comment: @fedorqui: Output will be: `FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02_` if I use `BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}`

Comment: @anubhava it is strange, yes. For example `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}NF=NF-2' file` worked perfectly to me. But `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {for (i=1; i<=NF-2; i++) {print $i}}'` shows all fields in different lines.

Comment: @fedorqui: If `print` is used then it does print line with a newline at end of it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(_[^_]*){2}$//'
```

For example,

```
$ echo 1_2_3_4_5 | sed -r 's/(_[^_]*){2}$//'
1_2_3
$ echo 1_2_3_4 | sed -r 's/(_[^_]*){2}$//'
1_2
$ echo FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02_20130820_181008 | sed -r 's/(_[^_]*){2}$//'
FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02
```

Comment: If there are one or two fields, this won't remove them. Not sure what behavior the OP wants in that case.

Comment: @Kevin Most of the other proposed solutions behave pretty different (some unexpected) with one/two field(s).

Comment: Yes, I've seen. Kent's deletes the line, Ed's will leave them untouched like yours. anubhava's will print an empty line. Just pointing out the difference in an unspecified case.

Comment: @Kevin Actually Kent's will throw `awk: run time error` for one field.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is the simplest way:

```
$ input="FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02_20130820_181008"

$ echo "${input%_*_*}"
FB_SYS_0032_I03_LTO3_idaen02r_02
```